# ModalPopupExtender calling .Show() does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, modalpopupextender

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and for database I am using Entity Framework 4.

In my page , I have 3 tabs and in Second tab I used Grid view for displaying the Details of Employee . In that Grid View there are 2 image button one for Delete another for Edit. I want to open a popup box whenever I will click Edit Image Button.

The problems are
1. Popup box is appear for a second only.
2. Able to retrieve the row index of the Grid view. But no value is pass into       other text box, it showing null value i.e. name0.Text= ""

In my .aspx page I have the following

**For Image Button**

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="edit" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("EmpID")%>' CommandName="edituser" ImageUrl="image/images.jpg" ToolTip="Edit User Details"  OnClick="EditUser_Clicked"> </asp:ImageButton>
```

**For ModalPopupExtender**

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="Toolkitmgr" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
         <asp:HiddenField ID="EmpID" runat="server" 
             onvaluechanged="EmpID_ValueChanged"/>
         <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpedit" DropShadow="true" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
            PopupControlID="pnedit"  CancelControlID="btnCancel"
            runat="server" TargetControlID="EmpID"></asp:ModalPopupExtender> 
          <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnedit" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: block;width:525px">

         ***Some Code***

         </asp:Panel>
```

In the server side code for the EditUser_Clicked event I have the following:

```
 protected void EditUser_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton btndetails = sender as ImageButton;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btndetails.NamingContainer;
        lblId.Text = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString(); 
        name0.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
        desig0.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
        dob0.Text = row.Cells[3].Text;
        email0.Text = row.Cells[4].Text;
        country0.Text = row.Cells[5].Text;
        city0.Text = row.Cells[6].Text;
        add0.Text = row.Cells[7].Text;
        hq0.Text = row.Cells[8].Text;
        rbtnListGender0.Text = row.Cells[9].Text;
        mobno0.Text = row.Cells[10].Text;
        this.mpedit.Show();

    }
```

The code runs without error but modal popup is not visible. Please help me to find my mistake.

Comment: try to put your markup code ie your Panel  inside UpdatePanel.

Comment: @ManishGoswami I tried for UpdatePanel also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There 3 ways You can use Modal Popup using Update Panel.Try any one of this.

1. Modal Popup with UpdatePanel inside PopupPanel

   ```
           <div style="background-color: White">
               <asp:Button runat="server" ID="button4" Text="Launch Modal  Popup1" />
               <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="modalPanel3" Style="display: none">
                   <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanel3">
                       <ContentTemplate>
                           <asp:Label runat="server" ID="label4" Text="Label in UpdatePanel"></asp:Label>
                           <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button5" Text="Click to Cause postback" OnClick="Button5_Click" />
                       </ContentTemplate>
                   </asp:UpdatePanel>
                   <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button6" Text="OK" />
                   <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton1" Text="Cancel" />
               </asp:Panel>
               <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="modalPopupExtender3" TargetControlID="button4"
                   PopupControlID="modalPanel3" OkControlID="Button6" CancelControlID="LinkButton1"
                   BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
               </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
           </div>
   ```

2.Update Panel that contains a ModalPopup and its associated PopupPanel inside it

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanel2" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="button2" Text="Launch Modal Popup2" />
                    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="modalPanel2" BackColor="AliceBlue" Style="display: none">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="label5" Text="Label in UpdatePanel"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="postbackBtn" Text="Click to Cause postback" OnClick="postbackBtn_Click" /><br />
                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="cancelBtn2" Text="OK" />
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="okBtn2" Text="Cancel" />
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="modalPopupExtender2" TargetControlID="button2"
                        PopupControlID="modalPanel2" OkControlID="okBtn2" CancelControlID="cancelBtn2"
                        BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
                    </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

3.Update Panel that contains a ModalPopup; its PopupPanel has an UpdatePanel inside it

```
   <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="outerUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="outerPanelTrigger" />
                </Triggers>
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="outerPanelTrigger" Text="OuterPanelTrigger" /><br />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="button1" Text="Launch Modal Popup3" />
                    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="modalPanel1" BackColor="Pink" Style="display: none">
                        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanel1" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="label1" Text="Label in UpdatePanel"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="updateLabel" OnClick="updateLabel_Click" Text="Click to Cause postback" />
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="okBtn" Text="OK" />
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="cancelBtn" Text="Cancel" />
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="modalPopupExtender1" TargetControlID="button1"
                        PopupControlID="modalPanel1" OkControlID="okBtn" CancelControlID="cancelBtn"
                        BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
                    </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: @Kusum check my update answer this will surely help you

Comment: Thanks used all your 3 above concepts in my code, but not overcome by my problem. So do help me to find the mistake.

Comment: Does this work this same when using a gridview with a linkbutton inside an update panel?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest version of AjaxControlToolkit?
In v16.1 the following bugs were fixed:

- [Item 27971 - Modal Popup incorrect z-index in tab container and
  update panel](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27971)
- [Item 28021 - Multiple ModalPopupExtenders z-index
  issue](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/28021)

Comment: Yes I am using latest version of AjaxControlToolkit (Version: 16.1.0.0)